# What query should i use to get the order id instead of the ticket id?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an adminpanel and i need the admin to delete and edit the order. Now i got this query:

```
<?php 
$results = db_getData("SELECT *, tickets.price 
                         FROM orders 
                         INNER JOIN tickets") 
?>
```

one problem with this it is not getting the correct id's the id's change when i add the `INNER JOIN tickets`

how could i prevent the id's from changing? any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

My table called orders is filled with an id, an userID, a ticketID and an amount

My table called tickets is filled with an id, a name and a price.

I only need the price from the tickets the rest needs to be the data from the orders table.

Here is my table:

```
<table class="w-full">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>User ID</th>
                            <th>Ticket id</th>
                            <th>Hoeveelheid</th>
                            <th>Prijs</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Verwijderen</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['userID']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['ticketID']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['amount']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo $row['price']; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="orders.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="Editbutton">
                                        Edit
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="server.php?delorder=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="Verwijderbutton">
                                        Verwijderen
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </table>
```

The expected output is all the data from orders and only the price from the tickets table (the order id's are counting up from 25). The output i get is this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo9oC.png)

Comment: Please add example data and ecpected output.

Comment: @juergend check recent edit please

Comment: Using wrapper functions like `db_getData` is usually a bad sign. Does that support placeholder values?

Comment: @tadman i know but it is a school requirement.... It does support placeholder values but the problem was not the function itself

Comment: Just checking as that's how really bad things happen if this were production code. Hope this assignment goes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other).   In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Right now, you have a cross join - every combination of ticket and order, regardless of whether that ticket belongs to that order.

You need to do:

```
SELECT *, tickets.price 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN tickets ON (orders.ticket_id = tickets.id)
```

or probably even better

```
SELECT orders.*, tickets.price 
FROM orders 
INNER JOIN tickets ON (orders.ticket_id = tickets.id)
```

Comment: Thank you @dave this works good for me!